# Call specific web service on -didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, web-applications, workflow

I am implementing the application which consumes webservice (first authentication and then calling different webservices with provided token as a header field in URL)

After the authentication phase, I am showing the Home page to the user.
On Home page i am showing UITableView (with 9 cells on it.)

If those were the buttons I would write separate 9 - "onButtonClick" functions to call 9 different webservices, accordingly.

What can be best implementation (or flow), for implementing this structure.

Let me know if you want more details.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep the URLs for the services in an array attached to the table view's view controller (or delegate really) and then use the selected row as an index into the array and call the service.

Comment: and what about the response to it. How to handle that... I mean writing nine different functions or how??? any better way for that???

Answer (score 1):

No need to write nine methods separately

you can use the JASON COCO way as he said store the URL in an array.

when you will click on a particular row. you should pass that URL to Web services method

suppose you have

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSString* urlString=[self.URLArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  [self callWebSerciceWithUrl:urlString];
}

-(void)callWebSerciceWithUrl:(NSString* )Url{

 //Use that URL String for calling web services...

 //You Should write your Remaining web service Code here...
}
```